# How to Fix WordPress Debugging Errors

Tags: wordpress, debugging, corruption

I have been having some weird behavior in the dashboard of my WordPress site. Out of the blue, my site started to appear corrupted. When writing a post, the publish button would dim after a minute or two and I had to exit the page and redo the post, saving immediately. Then my widgets stopped saving. I tried enabling accessibility under screen options but then I couldn't disable it. Then I couldn't even save a new post at all.

What I have done is: 1) rename plugins folder, 2) tried everything in the Twenty Twelve theme, 3) installed clean copy of WordPress from fresh download. None of these things worked. I ended up having to change my user settings in PHPAdmin to turn off the accessibility option for the widgets. So, after more research I added the Debug Bar and this is what it said:

Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /hsphere/local/home/boniandk/amorysabor.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3041 Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /hsphere/local/home/boniandk/amorysabor.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3041 Notice: Constant WP_MEMORY_LIMIT already defined in /hsphere/local/home/boniandk/amorysabor.com/wp-config.php on line 92

But now I don't know what to do. I don't even know if any of these errors have to do with my issues.

Site link is: http://amorysabor.com

Comment: Are you sure you [haven't been hacked](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19696/verifying-that-i-have-fully-removed-a-wordpress-hack)? I'd restore the site from a backup. If it's not a hack, the full helping guides are [Debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [Troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list). . . . Also, the debug messages are not site-breaking types. And at a first glance there's nothing malign in the site HTML code.

Comment: actually i discovered the issue was related to using cloudfare which seemed to be causing the errors.